# Group by hour in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

How do I group query results by the hour part of a datetime column in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I remember correctly you must first extract the hour from your timestamp and then you can group by that.

```
query(extract('hour', timeStamp).label('h')).group_by('h')
```

Comment: Oops... yeah you will need to do that. I updated my example. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 19):

This works for PostgreSQL:

```
.group_by(func.date_trunc('hour', date_col))
```

Comment: I didn't mention I'm using sqlite; date_trunc is postgres?

Answer (score 7):

Recently I had to do a similar thing using SqlAlchemy and MySQL and ended up using the DATE_FORMAT (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) to group by hour, minute, second

```
.group_by(func.date_format(date_col, '%H:%i:%s'))
```

To only group by hour it would be `'%H'` instead of `'%H:%I:%s'`

Comment: worked on MySQL for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in Python. Assuming you have an ordered `query_result` :

```
from itertools import groupby

def grouper( item ): 
    return item.created.hour
for ( hour, items ) in groupby( query_result, grouper ):
    for item in items:
        # do stuff
```

This answer is adapted from an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370997/group-by-year-month-day-in-a-sqlalchemy/1371029#1371029)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, use `func.trunc(MyTable.dt, 'HH')`

It is a bit finicky, however. This fails:

```
q = session.query(func.trunc(MyTable.dt, 'HH'), func.sum(MyTable.qty) \
           .group_by(func.trunc(MyTable.dt, 'HH'))
```

But this succeeds:

```
trunc_date = func.trunc(MyTable.dt, 'HH')
q = session.query(trunc_date, func.sum(MyTable.qty) \
           .group_by(trunc_date)
```

Thanks to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/TQWZUqV66Uw) for the tip.