# How to get month and year from Date field in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

The result should be Date object

Since the day cannot be 'removed', set it to say, 1st day of the month.

Leaving only Month, Year

Comment: You want to *store* only the month and year, or do you want to only *show* those two values?

Comment: I would like to _store_ (and group_by since i'm taking date from different tables)

Comment: not very clear what you are asking. it's python code, so just access current date and modify it to use 1st of current month.

Comment: I found an equivalent solution for SQL Server for a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date Maybe this clears the question a bit.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra: that would mean modifying date manually for each row in my queryset. I think there should be a more elegant solution using sqlalchemy. Also I need to group_by month, year

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use following constructs to filter the `Date` column using either `year` or `month`:

```
.filter(extract('year', Foo.Date) == 2012)
.filter(extract('month', Foo.Date) == 12)
```

And `group_by` is also possible:

```
.group_by(sqlalchemy.func.year(Foo.Date), sqlalchemy.func.month(Foo.Date))
```

Now I haven't tested it, but I assume that this might be slow because these queries result in full table scans, therefore I suggest you invest some time and learn how to use [composite columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/composites.html).

Note: `extract()` is imported from `sqlalchemy.sql`

Comment: Thanks. Does func.year or func.month work with all databases? I'm using postgres for production and tests work on temporary sqlite database.

Comment: @user1608977 I suggest you move your testing also to Postgres, will save you some time later when moving to production. HINT: Postgres is a bit 'stricter', so you'll discover issues sooner. And I'm talking from my personal experience :)

Comment: thanks, I used .filter(extract('year', Foo.Date) in group_by as well. I think func.year isn't available postgres, not sure.

Comment: @user1608977 Ouch, seems like `func.year` is MySQL-specific :S

Comment: Just want to note that I think this is an excellent answer in part because of the note at the end and the suggestion to look at composite columns.

Comment: @plaes not necessarily, you could have indexes on such expressions which could eventually prevent a seq scan, i.e. create index idx_foo_year on foo(extract('year' from bar))

Comment: With composite columns you would use `month`, `year`, `day` (`hour`, `minute` and `seconds`) and then build a date on the fly? Is that what you suggest when you say "I suggest you invest some time and learn how to use [composite columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/composites.html)."?

Comment: @cglacet Well, it depends on your usage... I have seen tables where there is a 'yearmonth' column to simplify some downstream reporting tasks.

Comment: Do not forget to the import: from sqlalchemy.sql import extract

Answer (score 1):

use next code

```
.group_by(
   sqlalchemy.func.extract('year', Foo.Date), 
   sqlalchemy.func.extract('month', Foo.Date),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you declare your schema like this,

```
schema.Column('created', types.TIMESTAMP(), default=now()),
```

the function now() is defined in the same module
which can be like this

```
def now():
    now_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    return now_date.replace(day=1)
```

as per group_by requirement, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370997/group-by-year-month-day-in-a-sqlalchemy) is a method mentioned.

you can modify hour and other field similarly.