# Write select request in python sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, group-by, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table with 5 columns (date, field_1, field_2, field_3, category) and i would like to sum all field_1

This is my sql request and i want to turn it into python sqlalchemy

```
select SUM(Conso_Tranche_Jour) AS Conso_Tranche_Jour, SUM(Conso_Tranche_Nuit) AS Conso_Tranche_Nuit, SUM(Conso_Tranche_Pointe) AS Conso_Tranche_Pointe, Compteur, DATE_FORMAT(Date_conso, "%m/%Y") AS Date_conso
from conso_ht WHERE compteur =%s
group by DATE_FORMAT(Date_conso, "%Y-%m-01"), Compteur
ORDER BY Date_conso ASC
```

And this is what i wrote but it's not working fine as i want it

```
consommation = db.session.query(ConsommationHT.Date_conso, label('jour', func.sum(ConsommationHT.Conso_Tranche_Jour)), label('pointe', func.sum(ConsommationHT.Conso_Tranche_Pointe)), label('nuit', func.sum(ConsommationHT.Conso_Tranche_Nuit))).filter(ConsommationHT.Compteur==current_user.Compteur).group_by(asc(ConsommationHT.Date_conso)).all()
```

Please any ideas to how i can process to do it ??

Comment: But does "but it's not working fine as i want it" mean? Do you get an exception etc? Do you have sample data to make this reproducible?

Comment: What does it mean to GROUP BY ascending order? Did you mix GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Comment: Sql request return exactly what i want, sum of each field grouped by month but sqlalchemy don't care about group by

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes i mix the two

Comment: So, are you trying to group by month (and "Compteur")?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes

Comment: Have you had a look at ["group by year, month, day in a sqlalchemy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370997/group-by-year-month-day-in-a-sqlalchemy), and ["How to get month and year from Date field in sqlalchemy?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019766/how-to-get-month-and-year-from-date-field-in-sqlalchemy)?

Comment: Thanks a lot @IljaEverilä i solve my problem