# Delete last month based on current month sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, where-clause

I am trying to delete rows in a sql table from python with sqlalchemy based on a condition.  Here is the code I have so far

```
def delete_previous_month():
     #creating connection object
     connection = engine.connect()
     meta = MetaData(engine).reflect()
     user_t = meta.tables[f'{table_name}']
     del_st = user_t.delete().where(
     user_t.c.month == Current_Month - 1)
     print('----- deleting previous records ')
     connection.execute(del_st)

delete_previous_month()
```

I need to get the part of the code where it says:

```
user_t.c.month == Current_Month - 1)
```

to delete the rows like it would in sql if I did this:

```
DATEPART(m, month) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())
```

What is the equivalent sqlalchemy syntax for sql server datepart function?

Comment: As (sort of) explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019766/how-to-get-month-and-year-from-date-field-in-sqlalchemy, the [`extract()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.extract) construct represents SQL `EXTRACT`, though in case of SQL Server it compiles to `DATEPART`.