# Filtering for a specific month in a range of a SQL database

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query (using sqlalchemy) to find temperatures for a specific month but i want the measurements for the month of june for all years in my database.

so far I have

```
june_temps = session.query(Measurement.tobs).\
filter(Measurement.date).all()
```

im stuck on the measurement.date portion and am not sure how to filter it. The database starts at 2010 and ends in the year 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the month as an integer:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import extract
...

filter(extract('month', Measurement.date) == 6)
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12024611/5316326

Comment: tyty this solved it

Comment: cool! in that case you can accept the answer as the solution