# Group by the date of the datetime field in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, group-by, sqlalchemy

My db is MySQL.
My table structure is:

```
name: Unicode(255)
created_at: DateTime
```

By following query I can group the result by the field `created_at`

```
Session.query(MyTable).group_by(MyTable.created_at).all()
```

My question is, is it possible to group by the `Date` of the `created_at` field? I would like to distribute the data in the same date but not datetime in the same group.

Comment: I fear this requires tying your query to the underlying database functionality; what database(s) do you need to support?

Comment: doesn't [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370997/group-by-year-month-day-in-a-sqlalchemy) answer your question?

Comment: Seems func.date() works, thanks!