# SQLAlchemy query count all records in database according to month

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have an app built using Flask, flask_sqlalchemy and sqlite3 db. Am building the analytics page and I want to count number of records in a table for each month. The table with the records has a column DATETIME. I have some code that generates comparison dates for this month and last month -- below

```
today_date = datetime.now()
first_month_date = today_date.replace(day=1)
end_last_month = first_month_date - timedelta(days=1)
end_last_month_temp = end_last_month
start_last_month = end_last_month_temp.replace(day=1)
```

Using sqlalchemy filter function, I can filter records for this month using first month date and for last month using the end & start last month variables.

Based on this, I think it would be possible to write a for loop that finds the next date backwards and queries the db for a count of the records. The loop knows when to stop when the encountered records reach the total row count for that table.

I think this is not an effective solution. Are there any ideas on how to count all records in table according to month in a much cleaner fashion? Maybe a less known function in sqlalchemy or even a lambda function to include in the query?

Comment: This is basically an SQL problem, and the solution is to use GROUP BY. Start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052148/group-by-count-function-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: Seems to be the best way forward. Let me dig into flask_sqlalchemy group by to see if I can get it to group by date

Comment: I think one of the answers here will do:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370997/group-by-year-month-day-in-a-sqlalchemy